# Creating sheets using a template from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Here is the Spreadsheet [method I want to use.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname-sheetindex-options)

Here is where I am using it:

```
function getMembersFileSpreadsheet(name, folder){

  var folderIterator = folder.getFilesByName(name +"-"+"Member");
  if(folderIterator.hasNext()){
    return folderIterator.next();
  } else {      
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someID").getSheetByName('Part-1');
    var idOfFile = DriveApp.getFileById(Drive.Files.insert({"title":name+"-"+"Member", "parents":[{"id": folder.getId()}], 'mimeType':"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"},{'convert':true}).id);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idOfFile.getId());

    // this method works
    ss.insertSheet('Member Info', 0);
    // works
    ss.insertSheet('Member Progress',1); 
    // BREAKS, does not insert a sheet here, breaks.
    ss.insertSheet('Part 1', 2, {template: sheet});       
    ss.insertSheet('Part 2',3);
    ss.insertSheet('Part 3',4);
    ss.insertSheet('Part 4',5);
    ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));

    return ss;
  }
}
```

Please note my comments on where my code breaks.  The first two sheets are inserted (when I omit the template argument).  When I include the template argument, execution fails and my newly created Spreadsheet has 3 sheets in it, "Member Info", "Member Progress" and "Sheet1".

When I use the template argument by itself (in smaller app, specifically just testing how it is used and if it works) it works fine.

Any ideas, has anyone experienced this? If I omit the template argument from my current code, all sheets are inserted properly.

I would like to be able to format each sheet using a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a sheet *from another spreadsheet* as a template. This isn't allowed by  [insertSheet method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetindex-options):

> The sheet template must be one of the sheets of the Spreadsheet object.

A workaround is to [copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) the template to the spreadsheet where you want to use it.

```
var templateCopy = sheet.copyTo(ss);
ss.insertSheet('Part 1', 2, {template: templateCopy}); 
ss.insertSheet('Part 2', 3, {template: templateCopy});
// ...  more sheets created
ss.deleteSheet(templateCopy);   // copied template deleted
```

Come to think of it, `copy` does mostly the same things  that inserting with template does, except there isn't a way to assign sheet name or index when using it.